# How to change doxygen;s background images?

Tags: html, css, documentation, doxygen

I am trying to customize Doxygen's output, but I am stuck with the menu bar.

I generated the custom css and html files that doxygen provides by running

`doxygen -w html header.html footer.html customdoxygen.css`

In the browser you can see that the look of the bars comes from a background image named `tab_b.png`. If you manually disable it you will be able to see modifications to the css (like that ugly green). I want to know if it is possible to edit or remove it all together (beyond programatically altering the html output folder obviously).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following rule in your css:

```
.sm-dox {
   background-image: none!important;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Probably best not to use the default css but to use a separate css and set it through `HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` in the doxygen configuration file (see also https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#minor_tweaks_header_css)